# Laravel: Refresh a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

First Laravel Project. How can I refresh a div on a page, where is a slideshow, too?
I tried this, but not working:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('.View').fadeOut('medium', function() {
        $(this).load('/echo/json/', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 2000);
```

The div, what I want to refresh:

```
<div class="left">
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th>Barcode</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Netto price</th>
        <th>Brutto Price</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
@foreach ($summary as $summary)
<tr>
<td>{{ $summary->barcode }}</td>
<td>{{ $summary->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $summary->count }}</td>
<td>{{ $summary->nprice }}</td>
<td>{{ $summary->price }}</td>
<td>{{ $summary->summ }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
<tr><td colspan=5>Summary:</td>
<?php $help = DB::select('select * from helper');
echo '<td>' . $help[0]->summ . '</td>';
?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You dont have a fiv with the class view inside your html?

Comment: could you please try by adding jquery code in $(document).ready(function() {  /* your code*/  }); section